# How do persistent items work in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

Players in Battlefield 4 can drop a variety of persistent items: mines, medic bags, ammo boxes, recon spawn points, etc. How long do those items persist in the world? Do they last beyond player death?

From casual observation it seems items persist as last as long as the item isn't destroyed by weapon damage and as long as the player doesn't change loadout. Ie: I can drop an engineer AT mine, get killed, and the mine will still be in the world as long as I keep spawning as an engineer with AT mines. (This behavior is the only way a Recon respawn beacon could be useful!) But I'm not confident it works that way consistently with all persistent items, particularly medic bags, the recon T-UGS, etc.

Comment: I've kept AT mines that I placed despite changing to Recon and Assault.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to the fact that as a user if you are shooting at someone the bullets are yours and even if you die, if the server recognizes the bullet to be fired you still obtain a kill. What I mean is that since the weapons are persistent death objects, then those will stick around, health creates are support, those stick around until the use has depleted the resource. those should stick around but not 100%. Basing this off past experience with 1942, 2, vietnam and 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did some testing by myself in the Testing Range on Xbox 360, killing myself via grenades or various hilarious helicopter mishaps and then seeing what persisted after respawn. Here's what I learned:

**Despawns on death**: First Aid Pack, Medic Bag, Ammo Pack, Ammo Box, C4.
These disappear when you die, no matter what loadout you choose next. These may persist until you respawn, I couldn't test that by myself. The C4 is a bit weird; it occasionally lasts a second or two after respawn and if you're fast enough you can even detonate your last spawn's C4. My guess is a timer starts to remove it when you die.

**Persists as long as equipped**: EOD Bot, MP-APS, Radio Beacon, T_UGS, SOFLAM, MAV, Mortar, AA Mine.
These stay in the world where you placed them after you die, and you can respawn and re-connect to them. If you remove them from your loadout or change kits they disappear.

**Persists forever**: M15 AT Mine, M2 SLAM, Claymore.
These stay in the world where you placed them even if you spawn with a different kit. Note that there are limits to these items, like only 3 mines of each type. If you drop a 4th mine the 1st despawns.

Comment: Hm, I seem to recall my Radio Beacon staying put after switching to Engineer the other week. Guess I'll have to take another look.

Comment: I just tested it and the Radio Beacon definitely does disappear. It only disappears after you spawn though, so you can spawn one time as an Engineer on top of your Radio Beacon before it goes away.

Comment: That was probably why I was thinking that.

Comment: @Nelson The mines and m2 slams also depent on what squad level thing you have, there is one that lets you deploy 6 mines. Do all of those stay when you die and squad level is reset? Or will only 3 remain?

Comment: Sorry no idea, and that's hard to test solo.